# Android how to set up buttons look on older versions?

Tags: android, button, layout

I am trying to make an application on android. I want buttons to be transparent, like on the image right (when i run my application on android 4.2.2), but when I run the application on android 2.3.3 the button became non-transparent and white (like on the left). Is there any way to reach transparent buttons on older versions, to look like buttons on newer?

[image: here is the image of buttons]

(the application is in Czech language: I was too lazy to set up new English strings ;))

thanks for every respond, and I apologize for any bad English

Answer (score 1):

define a shape with a solid color and alpha:

myshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
</shape>
```

and save it insider `red/drawable`. Put as background for your button.

Comment: this isn't exactly what i was looking for, i want buttons to behaves like buttons, this behaves more like a TextView.

Comment: a Button is a subclass of a TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml file in background of button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

[image: btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark]

[image: btn_default_disabled_holo_dark]
[image: btn_default_focused_holo_dark]
[image: btn_default_normal_holo_dark]

[image: btn_default_pressed_holo_light]

Comment: it doesn't work for me, it throws error: No resource found that matches the given name